# Concat less files into single less file

Tags: less

Is this possible?

*file1.less*

```
@import "file2.less"
@import "file3.less"

.caller {
  .mixin();
  width:  @width;
  height: @height;
}
.something-with-a-background {
  background: url("@{images}/other-thing.png");
}
```

*file2.less*

```
@import "file3.less"
.mixin() {
  @width:  100%;
  @height: 200px;
  background: url("@{images}/white-sand.png");
}
```

*file3.less*

```
@images: "../img";
```

And have these compile to:

*allFiles.less*

```
// file3.less
@images: "../img";

// file2.less
.mixin() {
  @width:  100%;
  @height: 200px;
  background: url("@{images}/white-sand.png");
}

// file1.less
.caller {
  .mixin();
  width:  @width;
  height: @height;
}
.something-with-a-background {
  background: url("@{images}/other-thing.png");
}
```

I just want the output to be the files concatenated together in the right order depending on the `@import` statements.

**What I'm trying to do**: I want to be able to add a less file in my dist directory so people can use mixins/vars/etc. by importing my less file. But in development I don't want them to all be in a single file. So I need a build that'll resolve the imports for me.

Comment: Have you *tried* this?  Do you get an error?  Do you get an undesired result?

Comment: @cimmanon, notice that I'm compiling to a less file, not a css file. If it is possible to compile to a less file then please answer the question, but I'm asking because I don't know and I can't find information to answer my question myself...

Comment: I guess I am still trying to understand the purpose of the 1 LESS file. If it is so that your other LESS files can just have one important instead of many, you can always have one LESS file that simply has important statements and nothing else.

Comment: @JeffWhelpley, that's true. For some reason I hadn't thought about that, but this is what we do with CommonJS all the time. Crazy kentcdodds... Thanks Jeff!

Answer (score 3):

This is not necessary because you can simply do:

*allFiles.less*

```
@import "file3.less"
@import "file2.less"
@import "file1.less"
```

and that would have the same impact for anyone trying to do:

```
@import "allFiles.less"
```

as if they were all in that file. Thanks @JeffWhelpley!